# Swift JSON parsing (getting nothing)

Tags: json, swift

I successfully get data from RSS feeds all the time but I am having a problem with this one and for the life of me I can't tell what the issue is.

Below code executes, returns 200 status code and no content

```
    let urlTMC = URL(string: "https://teslamotorsclub.com/tmc/forums/model-s.73/index.rss")!
    let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlTMC as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)
        if let response = response, let data = data {
            do {
                let jsonData = JSON(data: data)
                print(jsonData)

              } catch {
                print("JSONSerial error")
            }
        }
        else {
            print(error!)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            print("DISPATCH")
        })
    })
    task.resume()
```

Comment: RSS is not JSON, RSS is XML. And in your case you don't need the `URLRequest` at all: `let task = session.dataTask(with: urlTMC, completion...`

Comment: Which line is actually failing?

Comment: Its not failing, its just returning nothing when there is actual data there

Comment: That's failing. Again, which line are you referring to? Which line is "returning nothing"?

Comment: Sorry its print(data) thats coming back with nothing for me.

Comment: Resolved.  I was having problems with the url, so out of my control, once I got that resolved the data came back encoded.   I just used the following to unencode it                     let rssData =  NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)